# Front end dependency manager for appending <script> tags in order

Tags: javascript, dependency-management

I want a dependency manager that will append script tags in order, and avoid duplicating  tags with the same src. This has been an issue with the CMS we use.

I put together something like this:

```
const scriptLoader = new ScriptLoader({
    "jquery@3.4.1": {
        "attr": {
        "src": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js",
        "integrity": "sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=",
        "crossOrigin": "anonymous",
        },
    },
    "bootstrap@4.0.0": {
        "attr": {
        "src": "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "integrity": "sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl",
        "crossOrigin": "anonymous",
        },
        "dependencies": ["jquery@3.4.1", "popper@1.12.9"],
    },
});

// global js
scriptLoader.loadScript("global", {
    "src": "js/global.js",
}, ["bootstrap@4.0.0", "jquery@3.4.1"]);
```

So when global script is loaded, it'll first load the `["bootstrap@4.0.0", "jquery@3.4.1"]` dependencies by appending them as  tags, before it loads/appends the global.js.

Any attempts to load global.js again will not re-append the script:

```
// global js - will append
scriptLoader.loadScript("global", {
    "src": "js/global.js",
}, ["bootstrap@4.0.0", "jquery@3.4.1"]);

// global js - ignored, already appended/appending
scriptLoader.loadScript("global", {
    "src": "js/global.js",
}, ["bootstrap@4.0.0", "jquery@3.4.1"]);
```

I'd looked into require.js but I'd need to re-write all my js files as require modules which I'm not that keen on.

Does anything of this sort exist already? Mine works ok-ish, but can be a little temperamental at times and would prefer something that's already out there.

Comment: `require.js` is exactly what you're looking for. Updating your code to be require.js modules is going to be faster than implementing something as robust from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

As @morganney pointed out, [Require.js](https://requirejs.org/) is designed pretty much exactly for this purpose. Many popular libraries export their libraries in [UMD format](https://github.com/umdjs/umd), which supports the AMD (Async Module Definition) logic Require.js expects.

Answer (score 0):

This will simply import asynchronously all the first level libraries in your object, using just JavaScript `import`.

From the network debugger tab, we can observe the HTTP code 200 success:
[image]

```js
const ScriptLoader = async (libs) => {
  for (const [k] of Object.entries(libs)) {
    console.log(k, libs[k].attr.src);
    await import(libs[k].attr.src)
    // Lib ready here
  }
}

const scriptLoader = ScriptLoader({
    "jquery@3.4.1": {
        "attr": {
        "src": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js",
        "integrity": "sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=",
        "crossOrigin": "anonymous",
        },
    },
    "bootstrap@4.0.0": {
        "attr": {
        "src": "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js",
        "integrity": "sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl",
        "crossOrigin": "anonymous",
        },
        "dependencies": ["jquery@3.4.1", "popper@1.12.9"],
    },
});
```